# How to update ListView with List<> in C# WPF MVVM program?

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, mvvm

I have some list, which comes from one class. I import into ViewModel with instance. How later import this list into ListView.

My XAML Page:

```
<ListView Name="lvdevices" Grid.Row="2" Margin="15,10,15,35" ItemsSource="{Binding devfuck}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView x:Name="gridDevices">
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="DeviceId" Header="DeviceId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DeviceId}" Width="50"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ManufacturerId" Header="ManufacturerId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ManufacturerId}" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="ProductId" Header="ProductId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ProductId}" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="SerialNumberId" Header="SerialNumberId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SerialNumberId}" Width="150"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="HardwareVersionId" Header="HardwareVersionId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HardwareVersionId}" Width="130"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="FirmwareVersionId" Header="FirmwareVersionId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirmwareVersionId}" Width="130"/>
                <GridViewColumn x:Name="DateOfManufaturedId" Header="DateOfManufaturedId" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DateOfManufaturedId}" Width="130"/>
            </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

My ViewModelBase:

```
public class Devices : ViewModelBase
{

    private int deviceid;
    private string manufacturerid;
    private string productid;
    private string serialnumberid;
    private string hardwareversionid;
    private string firmwareversionid;
    private string dateofmanufacturedid;

    public int DeviceId
    {
        get
        {
            return deviceid;
        }
        set
        {
            deviceid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DeviceId");
        }
    }

    public string ManufacturerId
    {
        get
        {
            return manufacturerid;
        }
        set
        {
            manufacturerid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ManufacturerId");
        }
    }

    public string ProductId
    {
        get
        {
            return productid;
        }
        set
        {
            productid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductId");
        }
    }

    public string SerialNumberId
    {
        get
        {
            return serialnumberid;
        }
        set
        {
            serialnumberid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SerialNumberId");
        }
    }

    public string HardwareVersionId
    {
        get
        {
            return hardwareversionid;
        }
        set
        {
            hardwareversionid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("HardwareVersionId");
        }
    }

    public string FirmwareVersionId
    {
        get
        {
            return firmwareversionid;
        }
        set
        {
            firmwareversionid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("FirmwareVersionId");
        }
    }

    public string DateOfManufaturedId
    {
        get
        {
            return dateofmanufacturedid;
        }
        set
        {
            dateofmanufacturedid = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DateOfManufaturedId");
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewModel:

```
Something cs = new Something();
        cs.mylist;
```

How to get this list into ListView. I am new in WPF and MVVM, so all the things get slower and I still harder understand :) Please for help

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding devfuck}"` - where is `devfuck` in your ViewModel? In wpf update is usually changing of bound property value and rising `INotifyPropertyChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

ListView is to bind with Collection.
Your Devices is single object. I corrected some code:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="262" Width="436"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Devices /> // HERE CREATE INSTANCE OF 'Devices' CLASS
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="DeviceId:"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="ManufacturerId:"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="3" Text="{Binding DeviceId}" />
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" Text="{Binding ManufacturerId}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
public class Devices : ViewModelBase
{
    public Devices()
    {
        DeviceId = 1;
        ManufacturerId = "1";
    }
    ...
}
```

[image]

If your want to bind data with ListView please refer here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0b73e1/mvvm-model-view-viewmodel-introduction-part-3/

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You do exactly what you're doing for `Devices` for the main VM -- create a public property and call `NotifyPropertyChanged` when it's `set`. That will cover when the value of the property is changed -- to take it one step further, you can use `ObservableCollection<>` to automatically notify the view when items are added, removed, changed or cleared.

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Vm : ViewModelBase
{    
    private ObservableCollection<Devices> devices;
    public ObservableCollection<Devices> Devices
    {
        get
        {
            return devices;
        }
        set
        {
            devices = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Devices");
        }
    }
    public Vm()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Your XAML page could be something like

```
<window
    ...
    xmlns:local=[[YOUR ASSEMBLY]]>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Vm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Where `[[YOUR ASSEMBLY]]` is your name of your assembly (e.g., `"clr-namespace:WpfApplication"`)